# $A$ and $B$ are $2 \times1$ matrices such that $A =XB$ where $X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & k \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix}$ be two $2 \times 1$ matrices with real entries such that $A = XB$ where $$X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & k \end{bmatrix}, k \in \mathbb{R}.$$
> If $$a_1^2 + a_2^2 = \frac{2}{3}(b_1^2 + b_2^2)$$ and $$(k^2 + 1)b_2^2 \neq -2b_1b_2$$find $k$

Hello, I am stuck in solving this problem.

My Work:

$$XB = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{bmatrix} b_1 - b2 \\ b_1 + kb_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

So,
$$a_1^2 + a_2^2 = \frac{2}{3}(b_1^2 + b_2^2) = \frac{1}{3}(2b_1^2 + (k^2 + 1)b_2^2 + 2b_1b_2(k - 1))$$

Simplifying, we get

$$(1 - k^2)b_2 = 2b_1(k - 1)$$

($b_2 \neq 0$ otherwise given inequality would hold true)

**Case $1$:** $k = 1$

Here, this will always hold true

**Case $2$:** $k \neq 1$

Now, any $b_1, b_2$ satisfying $(1 + k)b_2 = -2b_1$ would work.

However, the answer given is only $k = 1$ is possible. So, it seems like we should eliminate Case $2$. How do we do this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe there’s a typo in your question. $k^2+1$ should be $k+1$, and then your proof is OK.

Comment: @Feng No there is no typo in my question. Maybe, there's a typo in my book.